# Ormlite how can i mapping Blob data type?

Tags: android, mapping, ormlite

I want to run this query and mapping the result:

```
GenericRawResults<Equipo> rawResults = dao.queryRaw(
                "SELECT * from equipo e  " +
                        "INNER JOIN equipousuario eu " +
                        "ON eu.id_equipo = e.id  " +
                        "WHERE eu.id_usuario  = " + idUsuario + " ",
                        new RawRowMapper<Equipo>() {
                        public Equipo mapRow(String[] columnNames,
                                          String[] resultColumns) {

return  Integer.parseInt(resultColumns[4]),resultColumns[5],resultColumns[0],resultColumns[1],resultColumns[2]  }
```

One field in table equipo is Blob, because i saved images on this.
When i try to map this field i have an error :

> unknown error (code 0): Unable to convert BLOB to string

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BYTE_ARRAY)
private byte[] mData;
```

Comment: hello lancelod, i declared the field like that. My problem is when i implement mapRow to mapping the result query.

Comment: Hello Lancelod, Yes!